# How can i Customize User In Identity 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

so , I wan to modify my `User` Model , I want to add a new property named `FullName` (which is an `string`) to My User Model.

I'm Newbie to `Identity` And I Don't have any idea about how can i do this.

I'm using `Razor Pages Web Application` Project and have the identity 3.1 working fine but i need to add `FullName` property to my users.

i've seen the documentation of microsoft and some other posts but i don't understand them :(

Comment: [There’s an official tutorial for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: i seen it but i don't understand how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create your own `User` class, lets' say `ApplicationUser`, which will have to extend the `IndentityUser` class, so a sample `ApplicationUser` with `FullName` would look like this:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

You might also have to adjust your `DbContext` class, could you share it?